# Rails, First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails and I ran across this

```
<%= form_for @invite , :url => invites_path do |f| %>

<%= @invite.story_id=1  %> 

    <%= f.hidden_field :story_id, :value => @invite.story_id %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

I am lost at this tutorial as I can't find sample code.

what exactly is the :url tag? And can that be hard coded for testing?

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

    def create
  @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
  @invite.sender_id = current_user.id
  @invite.recipient = 1

    end

 def invite_params
    params.require(:story).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)



  end
end
```

How do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add new def in your controller

**def new**

       **@invite = Invite.new** 

**end**

Comment: one thing I want to know here the def new, and invite.new refers to two different things correct?

Comment: Yes def new is our new method which is called when you hit form for adding new invite. we need to send blank object to form , so we create Invite object using Invite.new , this new method for invite is come from active record.

Answer (score 2):

In regard to the subject line of your question, I assume that is the error that you're receiving. In this case, that would mean that your `@invite` variable is `nil`. In the tutorial, it states that the author is placing the form on the "`edit` view for the User Group." So in your controller, you'd need to reference that variable. Something like this:

```
def edit
  @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
end
```

In regard to the `:url` question:

The `:url` option is the url that the form is being submitted to.

Here's what it says in the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for):

> :url - The URL the form is to be submitted to. This may be represented in the same way as values passed to url_for or link_to. So for example you may use a named route directly. When the model is represented by a string or symbol, as in the example above, if the :url option is not specified, by default the form will be sent back to the current url (We will describe below an alternative resource-oriented usage of form_for in which the URL does not need to be specified explicitly).

Earlier in the tutorial you added:

```
resources :invites
```

to the `routes.rb` file. This creates named routes for invites.

You can see these by typing `rake routes`.

Which will look like this:

```
             invites GET        /invites(.:format)                                     invites#index
                     POST       /invites(.:format)                                     invites#create
          new_invite GET        /invites/new(.:format)                                 invites#new
         edit_invite GET        /invites/:id/edit(.:format)                            invites#edit
              invite GET        /invites/:id(.:format)                                 invites#show
                     PATCH      /invites/:id(.:format)                                 invites#update
                     PUT        /invites/:id(.:format)                                 invites#update
                     DELETE     /invites/:id(.:format)                                 invites#destroy
```

So, by putting the in the form_for `:url => invites_path`, that means that you'll be submitting the form to the '/invites' route, which correlates to the invites#index action.

Comment: I edited my answer, realizing that I forgot to add the relevant information for solving the `nil` error on the form! Oops! :-)